# SerializeJSON in ColdFusion 7

Tags: json, coldfusion

Can we serialize & De-serialize JSON in version 7, the same as version 8 & above with this tag?

```
SerializeJSON(theData)
DeserializeJSON(theData)
```

or did version 7 have a function to do the JSON convert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SerializeJSON and DeserializeJSON were only added in CF 8, so no, you can't use them.

You might want to look at http://jsonutil.riaforge.org/ which *"is to provide JSON serialization and deserialization methods for CFMX 7 and other CFML engines which are compatible with ColdFusion's Serialize/DeserializeJSON functions"*